# How to hover a button by what the input value is?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make it that you put two colors in the inputs and the button even before pressed is a gradient of those colors.

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <script src='color.js'> </script>
  <link href= 'color.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type='text' value='' id='left' class='input2'/>
    <input type='text' value='' id='right' class='input1'/>
    <button type="button" onclick="color()" class='but:hover'>
     Make Gradient
    </button>
  </body>
 </html>

 function color(){
    let grade = document.getElementById('left').value;
    if (grade == ''){
        grade = 'white'
    }
    let gradetwo = document.getElementById('right').value;
    if (gradetwo == ''){
        gradetwo = 'white'
    }
    document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right," + grade + "," + gradetwo + ")";
    document.body.style.but:hover.background = "linear-gradient(to right," + grade + "," + gradetwo + ")";
}

  .but:hover{
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 550px;
    top: 225px; 
 }
```

I thought I could do the same thing just making a background gradient but I can't :hover in javascript.

Comment: You can use `onMouseOver` event in Javascript, it's pretty similar to hover.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve. If you want the button color to chane after you have modified the content of any of the two input fields, you could use the `onchange` event on the text fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use css variables:

```js
const btOver  = document.getElementById('bt-over')
  ,   btLeft  = document.getElementById('bt-left')
  ,   btRight = document.getElementById('bt-right')
  ;

btLeft.oninput =_=> btOver.style.setProperty('--cLeft', btLeft.value )
btRight.oninput=_=> btOver.style.setProperty('--cRight', btRight.value )
```

```css
#bt-over {
  --cLeft  :#FFFFFF;
  --cRight :#FFFFFF;
}
#bt-over:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, var(--cLeft), var(--cRight))
}
```

```html
<input type="color" value="#FFFFFF" id="bt-left" /> 
<input type="color" value="#FFFFFF" id="bt-right" /> 

<button id="bt-over"> Button to display the gradient on hover </button>
```

[edit] **special delivery for beginners like OP**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="color.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="color" value="#FFFFFF" id="bt-left" /> 
    <input type="color" value="#FFFFFF" id="bt-right" /> 
    <button id="bt-over"> Button to display the gradient on hover </button>
<script src="color.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script part must be placed just before end body tag**

Comment: your code shows what i want but when i tried to incorporate it in my code it didn't work.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't detail the problem. Wrote the code down and it didn't work so I checked the developer tools to see what was the problem. It had a red line under the eventlistener for the left button in the JavaScript and said it "cannot set property 'oninput' of null".

Comment: @BPF I guess the reason is that my html code is different from yours for all of the HTML buttons / inputs. _if you have correctly placed the JS code at the end to_ `</body>`

Comment: I switched the script to defer and it works perfect now. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code.. too much changes.. but let me know if you needed explanation of something. Thanks

```js
function color() {
  let grade = document.getElementById('left').value;
  if (grade == '') {
    grade = 'white'
  }
  let gradetwo = document.getElementById('right').value;
  if (gradetwo == '') {
    gradetwo = 'white'
  }
  //document.body.style.background = "linear-gradient(to right," + grade + "," + gradetwo + ")";
  //document.body.style.but:hover.background = "linear-gradient(to right," + grade + "," + gradetwo + ")";
  var css = ".but:hover {background: linear-gradient(to right," + grade + "," + gradetwo + ")}";
  var style = document.createElement('style');

  if (style.styleSheet) {
    style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
  } else {
    style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  }

  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src='color.js'>
  </script>
  <link href='color.css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>

<body class='but'>
  <input type='text' value='' onkeyup='color()' id='left' class='input2' />
  <input type='text' value='' onkeyup='color()' id='right' class='input1' />
  <button type="button" onclick="color()" class='but'>
     Make Gradient
    </button>
</body>

</html>
```